Why are some properties lost when use different decorator to a function twice?
I am learning how to use decorator in Python. Here I use two different decorator to a function.
Why is the attribute call_count from the first decorator lost, after I use the second decorator?
Does it still exist in memory, but I can't find a way to access it?
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)

def count(f):
    def counted(n):
        counted.call_count += 1
        return f(n)

    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted


def count_frames(f):
    def counted(n):
        counted.open_count += 1
        counted.max_count = max(counted.max_count, counted.open_count)
        result = f(n)
        counted.open_count -= 1
        return result

    counted.open_count = 0
    counted.max_count = 0
    return counted


fib = count(fib)
fib = count_frames(fib)
print(fib(19), fib.__dict__)

I thought fib.__dict__ would contain the attribute call_count, but it only contains the attributes open_count and max_count from the second decorator

You're creating two different functions, albeit with the same name; why would they share attributes?

You multiple nested decorators. You can introspect these wrapper functions, but it's  a bit cumbersome.
closure_index = fib.__code__.co_freevars.index('f')
assert fib.__closure__[closure_index].cell_contents.call_count >= 0

You could use functools.wraps, but this only brings in a snapshot of a function's state at the time it was wrapped. So any mutations to its attributes will be lost.  So you could combine that with an attribute on the object that is mutable, like a dict or custom object class. eg.
from functools import wraps

# def fib(n): ...

def count(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def counted(n):
        counted.stats['call_count'] += 1
        return f(n)

    if not hasattr(counted, 'stats'):
        counted.stats = {}
    counted.stats['call_count'] = 0
    return counted

def count_frames(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def counted(n):
        counted.stats['open_count'] += 1
        counted.stats['max_count'] = max(
            counted.stats['max_count'],
            counted.stats['open_count'],
        )
        result = f(n)
        counted.stats['open_count'] -= 1
        return result

    if not hasattr(counted, 'stats'):
        counted.stats = {}
    counted.stats['open_count'] = 0
    counted.stats['max_count'] = 0
    return counted

fib = count(fib)
fib = count_frames(fib)
print(fib(19))
print(fib.stats)

Which outputs:
4181
{'call_count': 13529, 'open_count': 0, 'max_count': 19}


fib(15)
610

As mentioned, the double-decorated function has only access to the outer namespace
fib
<function count_frames.<locals>.counted at 0x10fef0040>
fib.__dict__
{'open_count': 0, 'max_count': 15}

Access to other function namesapaces must be done through function closures
fib.__closure__
(<cell at 0x10febfbb0: function object at 0x10fef0040>, <cell at 0x10febfbe0: function object at 0x10fef0180>)
cell0 = fib.__closure__[0]
cell1 = fib.__closure__[1]
cell0.cell_contents.__dict__
{'open_count': 0, 'max_count': 15}
>>> cell1.cell_contents.__dict__
{'call_count': 2547}

